# Cropped Word 2010 equations

Tags: microsoft-word, equations

I'm having lots of trouble with Microsoft Word 2010 cropping my equations. I have tried changing from professional to linear and back again and other things with no results...

Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image: Cropped equation]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the line height is too small. Check out the paragraph settings—they might have a fixed line height set, and a small one at that.

Comment: Great, increasing the line height fixed it